# зависает навигационное меню

Tags: javascript

есть навбар, который при скроллировании страницы цепляется к верху окна с помощью position:fixed и top:0; если понажимать по ссылочкам в набваре, которые цепляются к id секций страницы, то через некоторое время все зависает во всех браузерах. в консоле мозиллы естественно предупреждение о наличии скриптов со скроллом, а в хроме после зависания спамится(даже сейчас, во время создания темки):

```
[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 296ms
mss_4.js:1 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 306ms
mss_4.js:1 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 333ms
mss_4.js:1 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 302ms
```

чистил main js, зависало чуть позже, отключение js в браузере решает проблему. с чем может быть связано?
https://vsenatorrent.github.io/ - здесь можно поиграться

Comment: Странно, но у меня не зависает "Google Chrome". Может проблема не в коде?

Comment: скрипты конфликтовали между собой почему-то, пришлось переписать, теперь другая проблема, оптимизирую верстку под google pagespeed, используя инлайновые стили в хеде, но на гитхабе подключаются свои стили, которые накладываются поверх моих и разрушают мне почти все)